# error installing 'create-react-native-app' npm

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I am getting this issue while installing the `create-react-native-app` app

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-native-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND genproxy genproxy:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-14T08_10_48_970Z-debug.log
```

I have tried removing any proxy that I was using still getting the same error.

```
C:\             
λ npm -v        
5.5.1           

C:\             
node -v       
v8.9.1
```

Let me know if more info is needed.
Thanks

Comment: maybe you should paste a complete log, that the terminal log refers to in the last 2 lines.

Comment: @Eduard thanks, Complete wasn't adding any more info, So I put only terminal log here. I was trying to resolve it. Got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was getting a wrong proxy which I didn't realised earlier.
I was under a corporate network so added the full name of the proxy 'genproxy.corporatename.com:8080' in place of 'genproxy:8080'.
Working fine!!

Comment: Where can i change the proxy settings?

Comment: You can go to `Control panel` -> `Internet options` -> `Connection tabs` -> `Lan settings` 
Put details under the `Proxy-server` section.